# Would cooking a leg of lamb for 12 hours be a problem?

Tags: oven, slow-cooking, lamb

I found a nice recipe for a leg of lamb. It is however supposed to be baked for four hours.

It would be more practical for me if I could let it bake for 12 hours (overnight) -- **would 12 hours vs. 4 hours be a problem?**

I was planning to seal the pot and set the oven to 110°C (230°F)

EDIT: did it. 2 hours at 180C then 12 hours at 90C. The it was sealed with plastic foil (heat resistant) It was fantastic.

Comment: 12-hour, slow roasted lamb. Man that is going to be delicious.

Comment: One thing is, this is kind of inefficient in terms of energy consumption. If moisture is a concern and you would use a plastic bag anyway,  poach it in water in a insulated container (slow cooker?) then somehow brown the surface afterwards would save you a lot of electricity.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem. I would probably use a lower cooking temperature however. Start with a highish temperature of about 180-200C, to bring the meat out of the danger zone quickly, then lower it to 80-90 for a long slow cook. You will probably want to introduce some liquid to the pan to avoid it all drying out.

Comment: Thank you, also for the temperature advice. I was planning to seal the pot it will be cooked in, to avoid loss of fluids. Would that be an alternative to adding liquid?

Comment: @WoJ Sealing a pot to be airtight and then heating it sounds like a recipe for an explosion...

Comment: @Beska: That's a good point but I usually seal it with a plastic foil (I've done it many times) and it just stays as it. If for some reason the air absolutely wanted to escape, it will have ample possibilities before an explosion - the seal being weak (good enought to keep the moisture in).

Comment: I don't cook lamb for that long, but I do cook it in a large enamelled pot which has a lid that just sits on the port.  It's tight enough to keep most moisture in, but not so tight that it causes any problem with pressure.    I also start off hot (220C) for the first 25 minutes, not so much because of any danger zone, but to give the skin a good browning.

Comment: Are you sure 80-90C will be warm enough to actually cook the thing rather than merely keep it very warm? Asking, because [following this recipe](https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/75-c-egg) at a slightly lower than recommended temperature basically yields raw egg.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy denaturing of most of the proteins that make meat "tough" happens between 55c and 65c. Anything above that will cook the meat just fine.

Answer (score -2):

Fry it in the pan, the marinade in wine for a day  then you can cook it even at 70 degrees C. Just apply some liquid every half hour or so- its delicious

Comment: OP wants to cook it overnight, so I doubt they will want to add liquid every 30 min.